# How to select a group within a “parent” group to move it around?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have Photoshop documents with layers organized into groups, and some of the groups are nested within other groups.

When I move them around, auto-select is set to `group`. The whole "parent" group moves. I have 5 other groups within, which means all 5 are moving. This is not what I want.

I would like to be able to select a group within parent/top group and move it individually.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi galanonim, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Just click on the group that you want to move in the Layers Panel

Answer (score 3):

Everything inside a group will move together, that is the point of grouping objects. If you want to move a child group then you will need to select the inner group in the layers panel.

**Auto-Select will not select the inner groups but will only select the Parent Group**. To select inner groups you must make sure `Auto-Select` is unchecked.

Your groups might look something like this. 1 Parent group holding several child groups. You must manually select the inner group. Now everything in `Child Group 1` will move together but `Child Group 2` & `Child Group 3` will not be effected.

[image: groups]

Comment: Once you deselect Auto-Select you can just right click on your image to select the Group.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answer, there is no native way to select nested groups in Photoshop on the Canvas directly. But there is a shortcut for selecting nested layers **(not groups)**

With the Move tool selected, hold <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click on the visible part of the layer and it will be selected and movable. Just the layer (not the group).

I thought it was worth mentioning.